# How do North Americans use toilet paper?

Tags: germany, local-customs, north-america, toiletries

I saw a joke on an American late-night show about that Germans fold their toilet paper. I got confused. As a German myself I thought "Wait what? What's wrong with that?" and I assumed North Americans use single sheets of toilet paper. But recently I watched an episode of "F is for Family" where workers at an airport complain about having to use single sheets.

After some research I found that it seems to be best practice to use more than single sheets (see e.g. the presumably north-american website http://www.howtowipeyourbutt.com/), which, since "when in rome...", makes me wonder:

Is it common practice in North-America to use several sheets of toilet paper at once? If yes, why would the joke be funny?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: Agreed, with David. No one is using toilet paper on you except yourself, and if they are, in going to assume you're paying them to do so, and they will do it in whichever way you prefer.

Comment: @choster: However, you will find yourself using the "local toilet paper style" while travelling, because that's what's provided everywhere, so you're not entirely sh!tting in a bubble.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Huh? It's the same paper. You can use it exactly how you use it at home. What Americans do makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, I was mostly joking... though I think there's a reasonable counterpoint to what choster said, which is that you are _to some degree_ at the whims of the local custom, if said local custom involves toilet paper being substantially different from what you're used to, and if you don't carry your own around with ya. Some locales don't even use toilet paper... Therefore, yes, this has to do with travel. (Sort of. But also kind of not.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK. But toilet paper in north America is no different from toilet paper in Europe, so that point is moot.

Comment: @DavidRicherby As it happens yes - but that would be part of the answer, not a reason to dismiss the question :) _"Is there a difference between X and Y? If yes, what is it?" "There is no difference, so your question is off-topic because we only discuss differences here"_ Kinda. Meh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question is whether North Americans use toilet paper in a different way from Europeans and about why some joke is funny. Neither of those is a question about travel. **If** the question was "Is there a difference between North American toilet paper and European toilet paper?" then the answer being "no" wouldn't disqualify the question. But the question **isn't** that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My reasoning was that it is a question about a difference in cultures and this way related to travel.

Comment: @M.Stern And I've explained how this difference in culture has no impact at all on travel.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The debate is between **folding it** or **crumpling it**, it is not about the number of sheets. A single sheet would be inadequate in most cases in either form.

> I know this is a strange question. Heck, you may have never even thought about it before. However, when watching TV with the German boyfriend recently, a show mentioned that different cultures have different methods for using toilet paper. In particular, they said that Germans fold and Americans crumple.

[image]

Source: https://welcometogermerica.com/2014/11/toilet-paper-culture-germans-fold-americans-crumple.html

Then there is this [survey about bathroom habits](https://www.map-testing.com/assets/files/Am%20Std%20Bathroom%20Survey%20detailed%20findings.pdf)

> Folding versus crumpling. Overall almost 50% more people fold their toilet paper
>   rather than crumple it. Age increases the chance you will be folding rather than
>   crumpling. Women are significantly more likely than men to crumple than fold.
>   Spending more time in the bathroom increases the chances of you crumpling
>   versus folding.

**Must Read:** [The 3 Types of Toilet Paper Users: Which One Are You?](https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/the-3-types-of-toilet-paper-users-which-one-are-you-223515)

Comment: This is scary and eye-opening at once.

Comment: if you crumple, the precision should be phenomenal. If you fold you do not need aim too much.

Comment: We learn all our lives...

Comment: Trust the Germans to be anal about how to use toilet paper. hehehe

Comment: TIL I'm German.

Comment: _The problem of distributing bathroom tissue to workers presents inherent challenges for any office management system due to the inherent unpredictability of usage_ http://soquoted.blogspot.com/2006/03/memo-from-fedland.html

Comment: @AlexanderMatrosov It feels like if you crumple it does a better job of getting into any crevices  or wrinkly areas (speaking as a woman).....If you fold, it just kind of skims across the top.

Comment: Afaik, there's nothing "American" about crumpling. This is just another internet myth that came out of nowhere. I'm American and I've known plenty of people growing up who do one or the other. Crumpling definitely isn't *more* prevalent. Folding probably is, in fact.

Comment: And then there's [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Iwzn0WRHsM).